# Android studio "No debuggable applications" on android monitor connected to my android device

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I've tried disabling & enabling the ADB integration, Debuging the project, Cleaning the project, & Rebuilding it.

It all didn't work !

Note that only this project has this problem, other projects clicking on the debug icon solved it, anything have to do with the configuration of the project?

[image]

Build Variant

[image]

```
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "co.keymakers.detalassistant"

    minSdkVersion 14

    targetSdkVersion 24

    versionCode 1

    versionName "1.0"

}

buildTypes {

    release {

        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess debugging is disabled for your App.

Either in your build.gradle within the default config or a build type:

`android:debuggable="false"`

Or in your AndroidManfest.xml:

`debuggable false`

Search for these lines and remove them (at least for your debug builds). Also make sure you run your debug build type.

Answer (score 0):

On the left hand side of the screen is a view called Build Variants. Opening that will show you're default build variant. Make sure a debug build is set as the default. The default is what will be built when doing a run in Android Studio.

If there are no debug options you have an issue in your build.gradle file.

Comment: You mean under the defaults icon ?

Comment: On the main screen click Build Variants it will open a window with Module and Build Variant. Whatever is under Build Variant is the build from your gradle file that Android Studio will run by default. You need to make sure a debug build is selected.

Comment: Ok that looks correct could you paste in the defaultConfig and buildTypes section of your gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

reset your adb it solve the problem tools->android->android device monitor->show view-> select device in the down arrow select Reset adb

Answer (score 0):

install this driver to connect your phone to android studio

http://adbdriver.com/upload/adbdriver.zip

Comment: It works on other projects on my phone normally, only on this project it doesn't